# How To Enable USB Debugging For The Samsung S7

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, usb-debugging

I am trying to use the chrome remote debugging tools.

So I am following this doc https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

However once I have developer options enabled, I cannot enable USB debugging. It stays disabled(greyed out)

Please not I have done this several times with other devices. My S7 is the only device that won't let me enable USB debugging.

Device information: Samsung Galaxy S7, android 6.0.1

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

EDIT: I have tried before and after connecting my device. The USB configuration is MTP.

Comment: Did you try to enable USB debugging before plugging your device into the computer?

Comment: Yes I have tried before and after plugging in my device

Comment: Is your USB mode set to `charging` or `USB storage`? I believe it should be neither of those but do not know what the third option is called.

Comment: It is set to MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)

Comment: Yah, that's the one. I just checked with my S4 and it's on the same option. I'm all out of clues then, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for trying!

Comment: Maybe very obvious, but are developer options enabled? http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/651762-how-enable-usb-debugging-s7-edge.html

Comment: Yes developer options is enabled, I can change all other options except USB related ones

Comment: And double check that the ADB option in Developer mode is on. What PC/OS are you using? Also try other USB ports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [www.samsungknox.com](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/faq/usb-debugging-disabled-default-knox-22):

> **Is USB debugging disabled by default in KNOX 2.2?**
>
> From KNOX 2.2 onwards, USB debugging is disabled once a container is
>   created. The check box to enable the USB debugging is unavailable
>   (grayed out) and user cannot select it.

You can try uninstall Samsung My Knox and then USB debugging should works properly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried uninstalling from the apps page and it wouldn't let me. Assumed it was baked into the OS. How to uninstall https://www.samsungknox.com/en/faq/how-can-i-uninstall-my-knox

Comment: Worked on Samsung A3 6 as well

Answer (score 1):

On my S7 edge to use the chrome://inspect panel i needed to download this :
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117
the samsung android USB driver is required

Comment: Any idea where to get the Mac OS X equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Samsung does these kind of things, but this worked for me:

1. Go to "Settings"
2. Select "About Device"
3. Select "Software Info"
4. Look for "Build number" and tap 7 times on it (yes, crazy right?) and you'll see a message that says “Developer mode has been enabled“.

Now when you go to Setting you will see the "Developer options" there. Make sure it is turned on and that USB debugging is turned on as well.

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall my knox on android 6.0.1

1. Go to settings - applications - application manager -
2. Tap on MyKnox - click "more" on top right then uninstall.

I just got my debugging mode working again doing that.